# Call controller with Url.Action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have Url.Action:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Shop ", new {parts_id=@Model.Parts.parts_id, quantity = "xxx "})' id="lnk">To cart</a>
```

where I have to call the controller, and controller redirects me where I need to. But Url.Action just makes href: `http://localhost:60119/Shop%20/AddToCart?parts_id=3&quantity=2%20`. What I need to do, to call the controller?

Comment: Click on the anchor

Comment: You have a space in `"Shop "`. If your question is why the URL rewrite fails, try removing that space.

Comment: @DavidHedlund omg, I am so blind...ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller name has a problem. Controller name: Shop or Shop+space , please check it and try this now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Html.Action()` instead.

It's render output `string` from your controller

[See moar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String))